# Collecting movie ratings using a for loop

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I am trying to write a program for uni that prompts you to enter the movies that a movie club watched then from the movies entered it will ask you to enter a rating, the rating prompt loops until the amount of people who watched it have entered their results then you type 9999 to end the ratings for just that movie and then I need it to loop again to enter the ratings for the next movie.... I just can't figure this one out any help would be appreciated. At the moment it does what I want to up til the end of entering the ratings for the first movie then when you press 9999 it ends everything but I need it to loop to entering the ratings for the next movie...? - Kirsten

```
SENTINEL = 9999;

var movieList = prompt('Enter your CSV list of Movies: ','Aliens,Blade Runner,Gladiator');
movieTitles = movie_titles_collector(movieList); //output to function m

var movieRatings = [];
var i = 0;
var j = 1;
var k = 1;
var sumRating = 0;
var averageRatings = 0;
var integersRemaining = movieTitles.length
var movieToRate;

for(var movieIndex=0;movieIndex<movieTitles.length;movieTitles++){
    while(movieRatings != SENTINEL)
    {
        movieRatings = parseInt(prompt([j++]+' rating for:'+movieTitles[movieIndex]+' (9999 to end)','1-10'));
        sumRating+= movieRatings;
    }

}

function movie_titles_collector(m)
{
    //@ param m = string of movie names
    //The purpose of this function is to collect the movie titles and return an array of 
    //movie titles stored in movieTitlesList.

    var movieTitlesList = [];   //array to store the broken up string, movieList
    movieTitlesList = m.split(','); 

    return movieTitlesList;
}
```

Comment: I am wondering if I should take the while loop and create a function to collect the ratings and then call to it from the/a for loop. I have also tried this but am hitting a road block I just can't get it. - Kirsten

Comment: It's usually better to post another question as a separate new question rather then just editing your existing post.  Sorry that I forgot to check your post until now! Please post as another question and I'll likely be able to look at it tonight/tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors i found so far:

1. `var movieRatings = [];` should be `var movieRatings;`
2. `for(var movieIndex=0;movieIndex<movieTitles.length;movieTitles++){...`

   Increment `movieIndex` instead of `movieTitles`

Answer (score 1):

1. The real issue is that there is a while-loop inside of a for-loop
   when really you want to merge both those loops into a single loop.
2. While it is wrong to have `movieRatings` initialized as an array, in this particular case it wouldn't affect anything.  Setting it to undefined `var movieRatings;` like ViRuSTriNiTy said is fine.
3. As ViRuSTriNiTy pointed out you were also not incrementing your movieIndex value.
4. The last minor thing that doesn't appear to affect anything but you shouldn't do is that you shouldn't write `[j++]` but instead just write `j++`. `[j++]` puts your number inside of an array which is not necessary in this situation.

Here is the for and while-loop merged together to use `while`:

```
var movieIndex=0;
while(movieRatings != SENTINEL && movieIndex<movieTitles.length)
{
    movieRatings = parseInt(prompt(j++ +' rating for:'+movieTitles[movieIndex]+' (9999 to end)','1-10'));
    sumRating+= movieRatings;
    movieIndex++;
}
```

The above could also be rewritten to use `for`:

```
for(var movieIndex=0; movieRatings != SENTINEL && movieIndex<movieTitles.length; movieIndex++)
{
    movieRatings = parseInt(prompt(j++ +' rating for:'+movieTitles[movieIndex]+' (9999 to end)','1-10'));
    sumRating+= movieRatings;   
}
```

So... as you can see, you can have multiple conditions on the loop, `movieRatings != SENTINEL && movieIndex<movieTitles.length` (2 conditions), and as long as that set of conditions remains true then your loop will continue to execute.  Also, notice the different locations of `movieIndex` and `movieIndex++` between the for and while loop.  A for-loop is basically a slightly fancier version of while.